# How to save and load items in a WPF listbox with my.setting Vb.net 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I've done the settings in the project properties
to save me use code like this:

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
                    My.Settings.list.Add(item)
                Next
                My.Settings.Save()
```

To view or load I use code like this:

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    If My.Settings.list IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item In My.Settings.list
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
```

There is no error in the second code of the program but did not happen anything when used .. please explanations, what could I forget or do not I know?

Comment: What is the type of your list? is it a StringCollection? How it get initialized for the very first time? By default StringCollection is null and you have a check for that in your load method but there is no any code that initializes this collection for a first time.

Answer (score 0):

By default StringCollection is Nothing you should initialize it in your project settings:

[image]

Comment: yes I've done the settings on the settings tab. but an error occurred. it seems I was wrong.

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine. What happens in your environment?, both save and load procedures get actually called? Can you set the breakpoints and see they were hit?